# Azure: Only allow access to Web App from On-premises using VPN

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, vnet, azure-vpn

I have a scenario regarding web apps on Azure that I can't wrap my head around.

I have a Web App (not ASE) that is connected to a VNET/Subnet and I have setup access restrictions on the Web App so that only traffic from that specific VNET/Subnet is allowed. This works as expected and a 403 is thrown when trying to access the web app from the internet.

My problem is that the Web App is no longer accessible from the on-premises setup anymore either, and I am unsure how to facilitate that. I don't like to use IP whitelisting to enable access, but I don't know the alternatives.

Anybody with experience on how to access a restricted Web App from an on-premises system? All the examples I could find are about accessing on-premise data from a VNET, not the other way around.

Illustration of setup:

On-premises server --> VPN Gateway in Azure --> VNET --> Web App in VNET -x-> Internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Private Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint) are your friends :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you - it was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I see you wanna set a S2S connection using vpn to allow access to your on-premises networks(subnets)

You should create a **local network gateway** representing your on-promises and also you should verify your firewall devices is supported by azure to make sure that the configuration works. [Supported Vpn Devices by Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices#devicetable)